# RS232 port of scale

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybsq9.jpg)I want to get weight from scale
this is my code :

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('com3',
                    baudrate=9600,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                    timeout = 3)

print(ser.read())
```

but all I get is b'\x00'

you can check the image which explain how scale send information to computer (from manufacture's brochure)

Comment: There is no image

Comment: yes i will edit it

Comment: It appears that `ser.read()` reads just one byte.  Could it be that you just have to read more information from the stream?

Comment: if i use    print(ser.read(100))    it gaves me b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...

Comment: Given what I see in the documentation, maybe you have to just keep reading until you see a `0xBB`.  If that's not it, then I don't know how anyone can help you.  Your setup could be wrong, but we have no way to know that.  There's nothing else to go on here.